# Very slow display and glxinfo error on Centos 8 + Wayland

Tags: centos, intel-graphics, wayland, amd-graphics, opengl

I'm using CentOS 8.2.2004 and dual monitors with AMD Radeon RX570 and Intel onboard graphics. (AMD graphic driver is `amdgpu-pro-20.20-1089974-rhel-8.2`.)

My PC worked on Xserver a few weeks ago, but after recent kernel update, it works on Wayland.
After that, display is very slow as if it is not using H/W acceleration.

To check it, I ran `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo`, but it displays an error message:

```
name of display: :0
libGL: DRI2 mode is not allowed under Wayland. Running in DRI3 mode
libGL: Error! DRI3 initializes failed
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

I don't know how to solve this issue, because I'm very newbie about Linux display system.
Could anyone help me, please?

P.S. I know I can change the login to use Xserver. But, I would like to use Wayland if possible because of this issue, [Screen tearing (PRIME Synchronization 0) on Intel onboard graphic + AMD Radeon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560502/screen-tearing-prime-synchronization-0-on-intel-onboard-graphic-amd-radeon).

FYI, when I run `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo` on Xserver mode, the below output is displayed:

```
name of display: :0
libGL: Running in DRI3 mode
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/amdgpu_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/tls/amdgpu_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/amdgpu_dri.so failed (/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/amdgpu_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/amdgpu_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
/opt/amdgpu/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids version: 1.0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: AMD
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 

...
```